# Get SVG Element from Data Element?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

So, I've got a sunburst, and the data is structured hierarchically, while the SVG data is laid out non-hierarchically. That is to say, the data is nested, while the SVG structure is a bunch of flat g elements.

What I need to do is hide the text that is the data parent of the current clicked element, however, because the SVG structure is flat, I cannot simply use a .parent() selector on the SVG or anything like that.

Instead, I'm stuck with the data element's parent, and trying to determine what SVG element corresponds.

So, in D3, **can I select an SVG element that corresponds to a particular data element?**

```
<g>
<path d="M-6.429395695523604e-14,-350A350,350 0 0,1 -6.429395695523604e-14,-350L-4.9138952815787554e-14,-267.50000000000006A267.50000000000006,267.50000000000006 0 0,0 -4.9138952815787554e-14,-267.50000000000006Z" style="fill: rgb(0, 49, 83);">
<text id="Name_20150209-33_Depth-4_Value-187" transform="rotate(261.0230190507786)translate(283)rotate(-180)" dy=".35em" opacity="0" depth="4" root="0" text-anchor="end">Claim: #20150209-33</text>
</g>
<g>
<path d="M-6.429395695523604e-14,-350A350,350 0 0,1 -6.429395695523604e-14,-350L-4.9138952815787554e-14,-267.50000000000006A267.50000000000006,267.50000000000006 0 0,0 -4.9138952815787554e-14,-267.50000000000006Z" style="fill: rgb(0, 142, 240);">
<text id="Name_20150206-53_Depth-4_Value-153" transform="rotate(267.30141532780044)translate(283)rotate(-180)" dy=".35em" opacity="0" depth="4" root="0" text-anchor="end">Claim: #20150206-53</text>
</g>
<g>
<path d="M0,102.5A102.5,102.5 0 1,1 0,-102.5A102.5,102.5 0 1,1 0,102.5M0,20A20,20 0 1,0 0,-20A20,20 0 1,0 0,20Z" style="fill: rgb(204, 204, 255);" opacity="1">
<text id="Name_Institutional_Depth-1_Value-6826" class="isCenter" transform="translate(0,0)rotate(0)skewX(0)scale(1,1)" dy="3em" opacity="1" depth="1" root="1" text-anchor="middle">Institutional</text>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to rely on D3's data matching. The idea is that you pass the data you're interested in, tell D3 how to match, and then handle only the update selection. This would look something like the following.

```
d3.selectAll("text")
  // match the datum of interest to the existing elements
  .data([datumOfElementOfInterest], function(d) { return d.keyValue; })
  // now do something with the matched element
  .attr("...", ...);
```